# With jQuery, is it possible to daisy-chain selectors?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is it possible in jQuery to daisy-chain selectors like so?

```
var sData = $('#myTableRow TD:nth-child(3):nth-child(2)').html();
```

Comment: If you describe what it is that you want your selector to select, you'll get more accurate answers.

Comment: Be careful about overusing this - if any nodes change then so does the order of the children.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps you mean:

```
$('#myTableRow TD:nth-child(3) :nth-child(2)')
```

Which would be the 2nd child of the 3rd <TD>?

Comment: This helped me select the second "A" anchor element of the third TD element. Exactly -- just what I needed. Saved me having to do this the hard way, and it's good to know I can daisy-chain in this fashion. And you are right -- that space before the final :nth-child() selector is very important.

Comment: +1 since i don't have to waste time manually applying identical classes to each and every patterned element

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but that one in particular makes no sense, since the same `<td>` cannot be both the 3rd and the 2nd child of its parent. You can however combine multiple "pseudo-class" qualifiers that *do* make sense when applied together, like ":text:hidden" for example.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but you have to add spaces. `'#myTable TD:nth-child(3) :nth-child(2)'` means select the 2nd child of the TD which is the third in its parent.